# node - make axios requests until a condition is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, instagram

I'm trying to use a variable to call a method inside a `while` loop. My objective is to fetch all the images until the `has_next_page` var is true. This param is returned after each request from the online api. Unfrotunately the code didn't work as expected

```js
class Scraper {
    constructor() {}

    question(inputText) {
        rl.setPrompt(inputText);
        rl.prompt();
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            let answer;
            rl.on('line', (input) => {
                answer = input;
                rl.close();
            });
            rl.on('close', () => {
                resolve(answer);
            });
        })
    }

    startFetch(username) {
        this.username = String(username); 
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            axios({
                url: `https://www.instagram.com/${this.usernamee}/?__a=1`
            }).then( (response) => {
                //response.data.graphql.user);
                userId = response.data.graphql.user.id;
                //totalMedia = response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.count
                if( response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.has_next_page ){
                    currCursor = response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.end_cursor;
                }
                has_next_page = response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.has_next_page;
                //let nodes = response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.length;
                response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.map( (item, index) => {
                    this.processLink(item.node.display_url, index);
                });
                resolve();
            });
        });
    }

    fetchNextPage(userId) {
        axios({
            method: 'GET',
            baseURL: 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/',
            params: {
              query_hash: '42323d64886122307be10013ad2dcc44',
              variables: { 
                id: userId, 
                first: "12",  
                after: currCursor
              } 
            }
          }).then( (response) => {
            console.log(response.data.data.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges[0].node)
            //totalMedia = response.data.data.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.count
            if( response.data.data.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.has_next_page ){
                currCursor = response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.end_cursor;
            }
          });
    }

    processLink(imageURI, n) {
        let filename = path.format({dir: destinationPath, base: `${n}.jpg`});
        let file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
        https.get(imageURI, (res) => {
            res.pipe(file);
        });
    }
}

const ig = new Scraper();

// ref url: https://www.instagram.com/profile/?__a=1
// I thing that next code part is a bit messed up?
ig.question('Username: ').then( (profileURI) => {
// get the first cursor from ig api, if has_next_page is true fetch next page
    ig.startFetch(profileURI).then( () => {
//while will cause memory error ?
        while( has_next_page ){
            ig.fetchNextPage(userId);
        }
    });
});
```

I've created a simple class in my node cli script. How I can call the `fetchNextPage()` corectly until the defined variable is true? I get a memory error

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[38139:0x105002a00]    66288 ms: Scavenge 2026.7 (2071.0) -> 2022.1 (2072.7) MB, 21.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.711, current mu = 0.384) allocation failure 
[38139:0x105002a00]    66329 ms: Scavenge 2028.3 (2072.7) -> 2023.5 (2074.0) MB, 15.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.711, current mu = 0.384) allocation failure 
[38139:0x105002a00]    66375 ms: Scavenge 2029.7 (2074.0) -> 2024.9 (2091.2) MB, 10.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.711, current mu = 0.384) allocation failure 


<--- Last few GCs --->

[38139:0x105002a00]    66288 ms: Scavenge 2026.7 (2071.0) -> 2022.1 (2072.7) MB, 21.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.711, current mu = 0.384) allocation failure 
[38139:0x105002a00]    66329 ms: Scavenge 2028.3 (2072.7) -> 2023.5 (2074.0) MB, 15.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.711, current mu = 0.384) allocation failure 
[38139:0x105002a00]    66375 ms: Scavenge 2029.7 (2074.0) -> 2024.9 (2091.2) MB, 10.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.711, current mu = 0.384) allocation failure 


<--- Last few GCs --->

[38139:0x105002a00]    66288 ms: Scavenge 2026.7 (2071.0) -> 2022.1 (2072.7) MB, 21.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.711, current mu = 0.384) allocation failure 
[38139:0x105002a00]    66329 ms: Scavenge 2028.3 (2072.7) -> 2023.5 (2074.0) MB, 15.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.711, current mu = 0.384) allocation failure 
[38139:0x105002a00]    66375 ms: Scavenge 2029.7 (2074.0) -> 2024.9 (2091.2) MB, 10.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.711, current mu = 0.384) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->


<--- Last few GCs --->

[38139:0x105002a00]    66288 ms: Scavenge 2026.7 (2071.0) -> 2022.1 (2072.7) MB, 21.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.711, current mu = 0.384) allocation failure 
[38139:0x105002a00]    66329 ms: Scavenge 2028.3 (2072.7) -> 2023.5 (2074.0) MB, 15.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.711, current mu = 0.384) allocation failure 
[38139:0x105002a00]    66375 ms: Scavenge 2029.7 (2074.0) -> 2024.9 (2091.2) MB, 10.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.711, current mu = 0.384) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
Segmentation fault: 11
```

**UPDATE**

I've solved the first issue with contents fetching. Now I'm trying to face how to avoid a 429 server error to fetch each single image link unsing the `processLink` method. This is the error I get when the images url are fetched.

```
node:events:353
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:67:26)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:486:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:188:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:153:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:80:21) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'scontent-mxp1-1.cdninstagram.com'
}
```

This is the reworked code

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const axios = require('axios');
const path = require('path');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const rl = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const destinationPath = path.format({dir: __dirname, base: 'scraped-profiles'});
let collectedLinks = [];

class Scraper {

    constructor() {}

    question(inputText) {
        rl.setPrompt(inputText);
        rl.prompt();
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            let answer;
            rl.on('line', (input) => {
                answer = input;
                rl.close();
            });
            rl.on('close', () => {
                resolve(answer);
            });
        })
    }

    startFetch(username) {
        this.username = String(username); 
        return axios({
                url: `https://www.instagram.com/${this.username}/?__a=1`
            }).then( (response) => {
                console.log(response.data.graphql);

                this.user_id = response.data.graphql.user.id;
                this.has_next_page = response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.has_next_page;
                response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.map( (item) => {
                    collectedLinks.push(item.node.display_url);
                });
                if( this.has_next_page ){
                    this.currCursor = response.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.end_cursor;
                    this.fetchNextPage();
                } else {
                    console.log('Completed');
                }
            });
        
    }

    fetchNextPage() {
        return axios({
            method: 'GET',
            baseURL: 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/',
            params: {
              query_hash: '42323d64886122307be10013ad2dcc44',
              variables: { 
                id: this.user_id, 
                first: "12",  
                after: this.currCursor
              } 
            }
        }).then( (response) => {
            console.log(response.data.data)

            if( typeof response.data.data !== 'undefined' ){
                if( response.data.data.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.has_next_page ){
                    this.currCursor = response.data.data.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.page_info.end_cursor;
                
                    response.data.data.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges.map( (item) => {
                        collectedLinks.push(item.node.display_url);
                    });
                    return this.fetchNextPage();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    processLink() {
        collectedLinks.forEach( (link, i) => {
            let filename = path.format({dir: destinationPath, base: `${i}.jpg`});
            let file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
            https.get(link, (res) => {
                res.pipe(file);
            });
        });
    }
}

const ig = new Scraper();

// https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1

ig.question('Username: ').then( (answer) => {
    return ig.startFetch(answer).then( () => {
        return ig.fetchNextPage();
    });
}).then( () => {
    ig.processLink();
    console.log('All done');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is axios requests are asynchronous and the `while` loop does not pause while the requests are made. You have close to an infinite loop as a result and are probably making hundreds of requests.

A better approach would be recursively call  `fetchNextPage()` from within the `axios.then` until the `has_next_page` condition is met. I think you have it backwards in question and want it to not be true , but that is an assumption.

Basics using a bit of pseudo code for brevity:

```
fetchNextPage(userId) {
      // return the axios promise so it can create promise chain
      return  axios({
            ....
          }).then( (response) => {
              // store current data from this response

              // decide what to do next
              if(!nextPageConditionMet){
                  // return another axios promise for another page to current `then()`
                  return this.fetchNextPage(userId)
              }else{
                 // finally return all the pages
                 return storedPageCollection
              }                
          });
    }


ig.question('Username: ').then((profileURI) => {
  // keep returning promises to each `then()
  return ig.startFetch(profileURI).then(() => {
    //Remove while loop

    // return promise that won't be resolved until the next page 
    // condition is met in recursive calls made inside the function 
    return ig.fetchNextPage(userId);

  });
}).then((pageCollection) => {
        // do something with  the final pageCollection
        // that was returned in final `then()` of `fetchNextPage()`
        console.log('All done!')
 }).catch(err => console.log('Ooops something failed in the chain', err))
```

Comment: the `has_nex_page` is given by the ig api so this is the condition. It will be true or false and until it's true I need to fetch pages contents. If this is set using `!has_next_page` the condition inside the if will be called only if it's false?

Comment: `!false` is true. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT

Comment: not understand, sorry. If the api return the `has_next_page: true` when passed to the `if(!has_next_page)` it will evalue to `if(!true)` this mean not true. The consequent block will be executed or not?

Comment: Forget the `!` and reverse the execution blocks if it is confusing you

Comment: I will use a simple `if(has_next_page)` so the method to fetch other pages will be called only until the value of `has_next_page` is true

Comment: Since my methods are inside a class, how I can share a `this.myvar` between methods?

Comment: Need more details of issue

Comment: I've tested now the solution you've suggested but it's not working as expected. It will only grab the initail page that have 12 elements and the second one then it will stop. This is why I was trying to use use a loop.

Comment: Well it's making more than one request so must be doing something right. Is it a public API I can test?

Comment: it's the instagram public api. You can test it by adding the `?__a=1` param after a public instagram profile. You will get the response I'm dealing with to get cursors and contents

Comment: Really not interested in setting up account, especially since the docs say it is shut down. If you can create a sandbox demo in codesandbox, jsfiddle codepen etc I would help

Comment: you don't need any account. just try this link to understand. https://www.instagram.com/federica_calemme/?__a=1 It's not part of the API that tay provide into documentations. It's a simple workaround to get public profile data in json format.